# How to allow user to enter a text in java code containing a String?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception {
    String order =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String random = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    String cipher="";

    String plain_text="hashem";
    char[] p_array= plain_text.toCharArray();
    for(char c: p_array){
    int index= order.indexOf(c);
    cipher+=random.charAt(index);
    }


    System.out.println("Plain Text || "+plain_text);
    System.out.println("Cipher     || "+ cipher);

}
```

How can here i allow user to enter a text in the place of the code 
 String plain_text="hashem";
to do the function above ?
I want him to put a text instead of the text entered by the code

Comment: Take a look at the `Scanner` class.

Comment: Simple googling for "java read input from user" gives few good articles like http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-take-input-from-user

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, unfortunately I do sympathize. Someone who is a beginner, and needs to ask this question, often doesn't know exactly what it is they need to search for. His perception of the problem was: `How to allow user to enter a text in java code containing a String?` which would be hard to get a hit on. Also, their english is clearly not 100%

Comment: @Cruncher OK, I agree this may be hard at start but in that case OP should search at least for keywords like `java read from console` which gives even better result: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

To get a single line of input, use:

```
String plain_text = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: `String`is a class. Been coding too long in C# ? :D

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux AFAIK It's a class in C# too, it's just aliased.

Comment: OMG 
I Forget it , its go a way from my mind thanks for remember me

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Thanks, don't want to confuse the beginners with syntax errors.

Comment: @EngHashem You would first declare the `Scanner`, as I have done in the first line, and then replace `String plain_text="hashem";` with the second line. Every time you want to read input you would again invoke `sc.nextLine()` and store it in some variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String plain_text = scan.nextLine();
```

The method nextLine() will get the String the user enter after he press the enter key.